# Important photos that was on my phone

Tags: 7.5, windows-live

I had a Windows Phone 7, and it was stolen.
I thought my pics were backed to Google but i cant find them anywhere. Where does Windows Phone Backup pictures.

Comment: Can you check your OneDrive account.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has its own cloud service, called [Onedrive](http://onedrive.live.com), which was also formerly known as SkyDrive during the Windows Phone 7 days. Every Windows Phone device. by default backs up pictures in the **`Camera Roll, Screenshots and Saved Pictures`** onto the cloud:

[image]

Visit [onedrive.live.com](http://onedrive.live.com) and sign in with the Microsoft (Outlook, Live, Hotmail) account that you used on that particular phone, and navigate to a folder named **`Pictures`**, in the root directory of Onedrive. Under there, you are bound to see sub folders of the photos uploaded from all your Windows powered devices.

Answer (score 0):

if you had Onedrive on your phone hopefuly theyre there. simply go to google and type OneDrive and sign in with your previous Microsoft account and password. hope you get them